# orgmode math equation inline with sub and superscripting

Tags: org-mode

I would like to have a similar display of the math equations in orgmode like I have in latex/auctex.

Here is a small example (from the same org buffer):

[image]

I found here a similar or same question, but unfortunately without any answer:
https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/9nqa6r/latex_code_in_org_mode_does_not_fontify_correctly/

From this I understand that this is called "font-latex-fontify-script".

Do you know how I can display the math equation shown in the picture like it is done in the "begin_export latex" region?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The answer is simply remove the ```#+BEGIN_EXPORT... ``` ```#+END_EXPORT``` and type directly the expressions/equations.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to see LaTeX code with syntax highlighted outside of the export block? Or do you want to a [rendered inline preview](https://orgmode.org/manual/Previewing-LaTeX-fragments.html) of the export block? Thanks for asking your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sub and superscript fortification, I have the following code
in my .emacs file:

```
(setq-default
       org-highlight-latex-and-related '(native script entities)
       org-pretty-entities t
       org-pretty-entities-include-sub-superscripts t)
```

I am not sure if this is all needed for you, but you can always inspect these variables.

If you are interested even in a pretty display of latex commands such as
`\alpha` with it's unicode char, well that's another story.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick help!