# Org-mode set a global configuration variable for `#+OPTIONS: ^:{}`

Tags: org-mode

I add `#+OPTIONS: ^:{}` to all of my org-mode documents so `_` is not interpreted and displayed directly as a LaTeX subscript unless I use write `thing_{subscript}`.

How do I set this globally in my emacs config? I can't find the variable in the documentation and this answer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/59135/16023 does not seem to work for me.
Would love a link to the spot in the documentation that explains this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Export Settings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html#Export-Settings) in the manual for the variables corresponding to these in-file options.

In this particular case, you will find:

> ^
>
> Toggle TeX-like syntax for sub- and superscripts. If you write ‘^:{}’, ‘a_{b}’ is interpreted, but the simple ‘a_b’ is left as it is (`org-export-with-sub-superscripts`).

(emphasis added)
So the variable you need to set is `org-export-with-sub-superscripts`. The doc string of the variable (`C-h v org-export-with-sub-superscripts`) says:

> ...
>
> Still, ambiguity is possible.  So when in doubt, use {} to enclose
> the sub/superscript.  If you set this variable to the symbol ‘{}’,
> the braces are *required* in order to trigger interpretations as
> sub/superscript.  This can be helpful in documents that need "_"
> frequently in plain text.

For display, the appropriate variable is `org-use-sub-superscripts`: it takes the same values as `org-export-with-sub-superscripts`. The doc string for `org-export-with-sub-superscripts` says:

> If you want to control how Org displays those characters, see
> `org-use-sub-superscripts`.  `org-export-with-sub-superscripts`
> used to be an alias for `org-use-sub-superscripts` in Org <8.0,
> it is not anymore.

So you can add the following to your init file:

```el
(setq org-export-with-sub-superscripts '{})
(setq org-use-sub-superscripts '{})
```

to enable the feature globally both for display and for export.

As the OP points out in a comment, the doc for `org-use-sub-superscripts` is in the [Subscripts and Superscripts](https://orgmode.org/manual/Subscripts-and-Superscripts.html) section of the manual.

Comment: thanks, that works for export, but within the document display is still treating _ as a subscript markup. #+OPTIONS method changes both display and export, do you know where to look for an option to fix display? For example, `(setq org-toggle-inline-images t)` ensures images are shown in org docs by default but I can't find the docs for this type of thing for other style options

Comment: Edited to add `org-use-with-sub-superscripts`.

Comment: thanks! here is the docs link for future me https://orgmode.org/manual/Subscripts-and-Superscripts.html I've always had a hard time finding these variables...

Comment: I didn't know about that section: thanks for pointing it out! I added the link to the answer as well, to make it as complete as possible.